# JMeter - proxy recorder - I need to deactivate automatic user parameter replacement

Tags: jmeter

I'm currently working with Jmeter proxy recording. I already have a lot of user defined parameters, and when I record a new script, jmeter automatically replaces the values of the parameters defined. For instance, I have a parameter called `${Year}` and the value is 2017.

Whenever I record a new script, if the "get" contains a string, let's say 
1234352017449, in the recorded script this will be shown as `123435${year}449`
I don't want this to happen. Is there any way to deactivate this feature? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not answering your question on how to "deactivate automatic user parameter replacement", but for a particular issue when part of the string is replaced with variable, like in your example, HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder has a solution: check **Regex Matching** checkbox, which

> If checked replacement will use word boundaries, i.e. it will only replace word matching values of variable, not part of a word. A word boundary follows Perl5 definition and is equivalent to \b. More information below in the paragraph about "User Defined Variable replacement".

See: [help](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). That page also has **User Defined Variable replacement** section, which provides more details on how to make variable replacement work for you.